# Задача Доставка

Tags: python, c++, олимпиада

C. Доставка

- Ограничение времени   1 секунда
- Ограничение памяти    256M
- Ввод  стандартный ввод или input.txt
- Вывод     стандартный вывод или output.txt

Евгений — логист, и у него есть *n* товаров. За продажу *i*-го товара компания получит *a<sub>i</sub>* монет прибыли (она может быть и отрицательной). В стране, в которой живет Евгений, странные правила выбора товаров для доставки: Евгений может выбрать любой отрезок товаров, но только один, и доставить все товары на этом отрезке (отрезком называется непрерывная последовательность товаров). Для доставки нужны грузовики, в каждый из которых помещается не более *k* любых товаров, причем за использование каждого грузовика нужно заплатить *s* монет. Найдите, какое максимальное количество монет может получить Евгений, учитывая затраты на грузовики.

Формат ввода

Первая строка содержит три целых числа *n*, *k* и *s* (*1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>*, *1 ≤ k ≤ 10*, *1 ≤ s ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>*) — количество товаров, а также числа *k* и *s*.

Вторая строка содержит *n* целых чисел *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>,…,a<sub>n</sub>* (*-10<sup>9</sup> ≤ a<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>*) — стоимости товаров.

Формат вывода

Выведите одно число — максимальное количество монет, которое может получить Евгений

Пример 1

Ввод

> ```
> 6 3 10
> 0 -4 16 -7 3 8
> ```

Вывод

> ```
> 6
> ```

Пример 2

Ввод

> ```
> 3 2 10
> 9 9 9
> ```

Вывод

> ```
> 8
> ```

Пример 3

Ввод

> ```
> 5 3 15
> 3 2 4 5 1
> ```

Вывод

> ```
> 0
> ```

Пример 4

Ввод

> ```
> 10 3 5
> -3 9 7 15 -10 9 7 6 -1 0
> ```

Вывод

> ```
> 28
> ```

Код на Python:

```
n, k, s = map(int, input().split())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
max_profit = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        profit = sum(a[i:j+1])
        if profit > 0:
            trucks = (j - i + 1 + k - 1) // k
            cost = trucks * s
            max_profit = max(max_profit, profit - cost)
print(max_profit)
```

Код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, k, s;
    cin >> n >> k >> s;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    int max_profit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            int profit = 0;
            for (int l = i; l <= j; l++)
                profit += a[l];
            if (profit > 0)
            {
                int trucks = (j - i + 1 + k - 1) / k;
                int cost = trucks * s;
                max_profit = max(max_profit, profit - cost);
                
                
            }
        }
    }
    cout << max_profit << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Задача решена верно, но тут ограничение времени в 1 секунду. И я не понимая как мне ещё можно оптимизировать код на Python. Решил переписать на C++ но вот все результаты:

[image]

Кто знает как добиться 1 секунды?

Comment: Три вложенных цикла - это крайте печально для производительности.

Comment: Использовать правильный, *не переборный* алгоритм. Любая оптимизация должна начинаться с алгоритма...

Comment: так как быть то?

Comment: Сперва избавьтесь от `sum(a[i:j+1])`. Ключевое слово - [кумулятивный массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0). Может быть этого хватит.

Comment: Когда заканчивается соревнование?

Comment: через 4 часа(((

Comment: Не обижайтесь, задача интересная, но помогать вам пока идет соревнование я не буду. За честную игру!

Comment: Да я понимаю! Я почти решил!

Comment: чем вам sum не нравится? это же быстрая функция

Comment: @ZEf3344 Тем, что sum каждый раз считает сумму подсписка, хоть и быстро, а можно не считать, а получить её за одно действие

Comment: Про `sum` я написал потому что это простое изменение с сохранением вашего алгоритма даст немедленный выигрыш в скорости. Динамика по грузовикам куда сложнее будет - совсем другой алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть *p<sub>i</sub>* - максимальная прибыль для отрезка товаров завершающегося на позиции *i*. Тогда:

- *p<sub>i</sub> ≥ 0* - отрезок может быть и пустым;
- *p<sub>i</sub> ≥ ∑(a<sub>j</sub>, ..., a<sub>i</sub>) - s*, где *i - k < j ≤ i* - можно отправить один грузовик полный или не полный;
- *p<sub>i</sub> ≥ p<sub>i-k</sub> + (∑(a<sub>i-k+1</sub>, ..., a<sub>i</sub>) - s)*, *i ≥ k* - можно отправить полный грузовик (второе слагаемое) и вместе с ним ещё сколько-то грузовиков перед ним (первое слагаемое).

Список выше исчерпывает все варианты значений для *p<sub>i</sub>*. В каждой позиции *i* нужно вычислить максимум из *k + 2* значений.

```py
def max_truck(b, s):

    def acc():
        yield 0
        sum_ = 0
        for v in reversed(b):
            sum_ += v
            yield sum_ - s

    return max(acc())


def main():
    n, k, s = map(int, input().split())
    a = list(map(int, input().split()))

    profit = [0] * (n + 1)

    for i in range(k):
        profit[i] = max_truck(a[:i], s)

    for i in range(k, n + 1):
        b = a[i - k:i]
        profit[i] = max(max_truck(b, s), sum(b) - s + profit[i - k])

    print(max(profit))


main()
```

Код имеет сложность *nk*. Так как *k* не велико, этого может хватить для решения задачи. Если нет, то сложность можно понизить до *n·log k*, если применить кучу для поиска максимума в неполном грузовике.

Comment: Еще отмечу, что данное решение несложно улучшается до `O(N+K)`, если считать максимум в окне с помощью очереди максимумов.

Comment: @EzikBro, про очередь максимумов я и забыл. Спасибо! С кучей получалось уж очень много кода. И асимптотика у очереди идеальная.